# How can I conditionally construct a table name for an SQL CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, oracle, informix

Within an SQL stored procedure, I would like to have the ability to construct a table name and create it.

Example: I just logged into my database under company 03 and a customer table does not exist, so I would like for the proc to `CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER03`.

Is there a way to `append company_id char(2)` to `CUSTOMER` and feed it to the `CREATE TABLE` statement? maybe like

```
CREATE TABLE $tablename or $tablename+company_id?
```

Comment: The exact syntax will differ for oracle and those other DBMS's you've tagged.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Agreed!.. Can this be done in any or all of the db's I tagged?

Comment: No, when I read it, I assumed he meant he wanted to alter the customer table to append the company_id field.  Concat, on the other hand, almost always regards strings.  Note that originally he did not have the last sentence, making it more unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic SQL eg:

```
DECLARE @company_id char(2)
SET @company_id = '02'
EXEC('CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER' + @company_id + ' (id int PRIMARY KEY)')
```

(tested)

Comment: So, of all the db's I tagged, which one's support dynamic SQL?..Can PSM also handle this?

Answer (score 9):

In Oracle the syntax would be something like

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_'||v_company_id||' (..)';
END;
```

However this is probably a really bad idea. Six months down the line you'll want to add a column to the table and you'll need to work out which tables you need to add it to.

Also, stored procedures in Oracle need a fixed table name (of an existing table) or you'd have to reference everything through dynamic SQL which is a pain.

Better to have a single customer table with the company_id as an attribute. Then use [Fine Grained Access Control](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvcntx.htm#i1007660) to securely filter on the company_id to control who see's what company's data.

Comment: +1. Almost everything is possible but most of it is inadvisable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IF NOT EXISTS` modifier to the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  This will cause the table to be created only if it does not already exist.

Comment: Which db's I tagged suport IF NOT EXISTS modifier?

Comment: MySQL for a fact, but I believe all.